# hdparm doesn't show "security" section

Tags: security, ssd, hdparm

I tried to find out the security settings of my Samung 256 GB SDD used on a Lenovo Thinkpad T430.

However, sending "hdparm -I" provides the usual information but omits the "security" section altogether.

There is no BIOS entry that seems helpful either.

Why won't it tell me the security settings?

EDIT:

My situation seems to be a little bit different to that described in the other thread.

My SSD is a Samsung SSD Model MZ - 7TD2560/0L7 built Octobre 2013. WINMAGIC bootloader with WINDOWS 7 is installed on it.

Unlike in the other thread, I guess this drive is in principle "good enough" to support the ATA security feature set. After all, when WINMAGIC is bypassed by booting from another media (i. e. UNIX), there is no way to change the drive. All tools I have used so far (includig PartedMagic) fail on performing any changes to that drive. The drive controller prevents any write-operations. Thus, I conclude this drive is far too clever not to know about security settings.

However, hdparm -I returns, amongst others, in the "Commands/features" section only the following

SET_MAX security extension SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA command

but omits the "Security" section altogether.

I understand from the other thread that the "security" section is omitted if a drive just doesn't have any security features. But is there any reason why an SSD would disguise (!) its (existing) security capability?

Comment: See this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/62867) by Tom Leek on Information Security. Seems like your drive doesn't claim to support any kind of security features