# Security features disabled by DCO - how to unfreeze and restore?

Tags: security, hdparm

I use a Samung 256 GB SDD Model MZ - 7TD2560/0L7 built Octobre 2013. WINMAGIC bootloader with WINDOWS 7 is installed on it.

`hdparm -I` doesn't report any security features for that drive.

`hdparm --dco-identify` tells me that security feature set might have been disabled by DCO, so I guess this is what happened [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361230/hdparm-doesnt-show-security-section/361691#361230).

Tried to restore factory setting via `--dco-restore` but only got I/O error.

How can I restore the security feature set?